# Disappearing logout button with html, jquery, and php

Tags: php, jquery, logout

I'm a very green programmer and can't find an answer anywhere on the web for my problem.  Thanks for any help you send my way! I'm trying to make a basic login page for users that allows an upload and also allows the user to logout. During login, I start a session. It works.  For both the upload and the logout, I'm using the jquery.form.js library to take advantage of the form functionality. For the upload portion of my code, everything works fine. The user can upload images of any type, the button is deactivated during the upload, then reactivated after success for new uploads. However, for the logout portion, after clicking the logout button and destroying the session, the logout button just disappears. I thought that it may have to do with the session destroy, but even without that in my php, the button is gone.  I copied the logout portion of my code below, in order, html, js, and php.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <meta http-equiv= "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.form.js"></script>    
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/xmlRequest.js"></script>
            <script>xmlRequest = new xmlRequest();</script>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/fileUpload.js"></script>
            <script>fileUpload = new fileUpload();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'userLogout'>
            <form action="php/logout.php" id = "logoutSection" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post" >
                <button type="submit" id="logoutButton">Close!</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id = 'logOutOutput'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



function fileUpload()
{   
$(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $('#logoutSection').on('submit',function(a){

                //prevent default action of going to new page.
                a.preventDefault();
                $('#logoutButton').attr('disabled','');
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: '#userLogout',
                    success: afterLogout//output a thank you message
                });
                $('#loginForm').show();
                $('#logOutOutput').append("<br>Thanks for checking us out!<br>");
            });
    });

    function afterLogout()
    {
        $('#logoutSection').resetForm();
        $('#logoutButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}


<?php
    echo "<br>Goner<br>";
    session_start();//always required for sessions
    session_destroy();//logs out
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe although I'm not sure that the reason why the button is gone after login out is because you are using `ajaxSubmit` with the option `target` set to `#userLogout` which points to the parent div of the form.

After the ajaxSubmit is success it will replace the content of `<div id='userLogout'> ... </div>` with the result of of the ajax operation.

I would it this way: 
    `<div id='output'></div> <div id = 'userLogout'>
    <form action="php/logout.php" id = "logoutSection" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post" >
    <button type="submit" id="logoutButton">Close!</button>
    </form>
    </div>`

and change ajaxSubmit target to `target: 'output'`

Read this 
http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/ajaxform-and-ajaxsubmit-options/
target
Identifies the element(s) in the page to be updated with the server response. This value may be specified as a jQuery selection string, a jQuery object, or a DOM element.
Default value: null

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I can't believe I missed this.  In the upload section, I was changing a different target than the upload div.  In the logout section, I was replacing everything.  I just tried your suggestion, and it worked.  Much appreciated man!